FastColoredTextBox XML Forecolor
Just added a fastcoloredtextbox to my Winform and set language to XML. Cannot change the styling. How can i change the blue and red colors.
using FastColoredTextBoxNS;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JFlowV2
{
    public partial class BaseFastColoredTextBox : FastColoredTextBox
    {
        public BaseFastColoredTextBox()
        {
            this.Load += BaseFastColoredTextBox_Load;
        }

        private void BaseFastColoredTextBox_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyDarkTheme();
        }

        public void ApplyDarkTheme()
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30); // Editor background
            this.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220); // Editor text
            this.IndentBackColor = Color.FromArgb(45, 45, 48); // Indentation background
            this.ServiceLinesColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50); // Service lines
            this.LineNumberColor = Color.FromArgb(43, 145, 175); // Line numbers
            this.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(60, 75, 110, 175); // Selection color
            this.CurrentLineColor = Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 40); // Current line highlight

        }
    }
}


You need to modify the styles applied to each XML element (such as tags, attributes, and values). You also need to override the styles used for XML Tokens by defining your own Text style
So in your case add to the existing code in ApplyDarkTheme() something like this
 tagStyle = new TextStyle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue), null, FontStyle.Regular);         // Color for tags
        attributeNameStyle = new TextStyle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightCoral), null, FontStyle.Regular); // Color for attribute names
        attributeValueStyle = new TextStyle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGreen), null, FontStyle.Regular); // Color for attribute values

        // Apply the custom styles
        this.Language = Language.Custom;
        this.ClearStylesBuffer();
        this.AddStyle(tagStyle);
        this.AddStyle(attributeNameStyle);
        this.AddStyle(attributeValueStyle);

        // Set up the rules for XML elements
        this.Range.ClearStyle(StyleIndex.All);
        this.Range.SetStyle(tagStyle, @"</?[a-zA-Z]+");                       // Tag name (e.g., <tag> or </tag>)
        this.Range.SetStyle(attributeNameStyle, @"\b[a-zA-Z0-9_:-]+(?=\=)");   // Attribute names (e.g., name=)
        this.Range.SetStyle(attributeValueStyle, @"""[^""]*""");               // Attribute values (e.g., "value")

If you want to read more about this I recommend following https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

thank you for explaining and wrote a code for me. But can you explain why i cant only change it from properties menu just like other components i use on my project ?

The keydifference in this lies in component behaving. While most classic WinForms controls rely on properties that Windows forms natively support, like ForeColor and BackColor, for simple styling. FastColoredTextBox doesn't. They support more complex syntax highlighting which require defining specific styles. This goes beyond the scope of the typical properties of the designer. (Involves mapping colors to specific syntax which isn't WinForms native) This means FastColoredTextBox requires code to set up language-specific formatting rules explicitly.

Or what may be simpler to understand: FastColoredTextBox handles everything internally. WinForms uses default Windows properties instead.

Thank you very much and have a nice day sir
